# .NET MVC Preserve Session on deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I have a single server with multiple IIS instances with each one having its own app pool pointed to a single folder that contains the site.  When I deploy the site the app pools recycle which I expected but my question is: Is it possible to avoid connected users from losing their sessions and if so, how.

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using a sql session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sessions are resetting when the app pool recycles, you are using InProc session management.  You can fix that by backing your session management with SQL or other persisted storage.

Helpful link from CodeProject with the 10,000 ft view below.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416137/Understanding-Session-Management-Techniques-in-ASP